# np.nditer return type for reference types

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

How can I get the right return type for np.nditer? I need to iterate through `ax` object here:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9), ncols=3, nrows=2)
for col, elem in zip(df.columns[:-1], np.nditer(ax, flags = ['refs_ok'])):
    sns.countplot(x="CLASS", hue=col, data=df, ax=elem)
```

I know I could have iterated here using the dimension of ax array, but I wonder, if I can make this work. Basically, `ax=elem` should look like `ax=ax[i][j]` in iteration. But it turns out they have different types:

```
print(type(elem))
print(type(ax[0][0]))
```

returns:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

Comment: `nditer` is a specialized iterator, and isn't needed for most `numpy` work.  As you found, it produces arrays (single element 0d).  `elem.item()` is probably `ax[0,0]`.  But the `ax.flat` used by the accepted answer is a better iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you want to iterate like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9), ncols=3, nrows=2)
for col, elem in zip(df.columns[:-1], ax.flat):
    sns.countplot(x="CLASS", hue=col, data=df, ax=elem)
```

which is shorter and always makes `elem` an `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a `numpy` function like this is that it will convert the iterable to an `np.ndarray` object straight away.

Therefore, your return value will be a slice of this `np.ndarray` object have a look at the following example

```
In [472]: list(np.nditer([[None, None], [None, None]], flags = ['refs_ok']))
Out[472]:
[(array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object)),
 (array(None, dtype=object), array(None, dtype=object))]

In [473]: list(np.nditer([[None, None], [None, None]], flags = ['refs_ok']))[0][0]
Out[473]: array(None, dtype=object)
```

If you want the raw item from a 0 dimensional `numpy` array then use the `.tolist()` method

As you're probably now aware, since you're not iterating numeric types, it doesn't make sense to introduce all this `numpy` complexity and overhead the correct way to do this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316861/4013571